# Can I receive a stream over HTTP with JavaScript, Flash, or Silverlight?

Tags: javascript, http, streaming

I'm prototyping a realtime notification mechanism using http over port 80. The aim of the project is to allow a Flash application to respond to an event on a remote server quickly (specifically an inbound phone call being connected to a phone next to the computer.) Polling is one approach, but is too slow. Currently I use a socket connection to get low latency notification of the events on the server, which works well but isn't firewall friendly. I don't want to install anything except Flash, or Silverlight on the client. Cross compatibility of browsers isn't a concern - in this application I can specify what browser the client uses but IE is preferred.

I've made a server HttpHandler in .NET which never closes the connection and sends the "events" to the client by writing out bytes to the http response stream (ConnectedClientContext.Response.OutputStream.Write etc) and I have a .NET client application which can read these messages okay.

My Question:

Can I receive the bytes from the server over HTTP as they arrive using JavaScript, Flash or Silverlight? So far I can only find a way to get notified of the "download progress" and don't get the actual bytes until the response is closed - I want them as they arrive.

Best Regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about Flash but in Javascript (by which you mean in browser) and Silverlight you are limited pretty much to the http protocol.

You can use the [AJAX Http Streaming pattern](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming).  The basic ideas which is different from what you are trying is that as soon as data is available outstanding request ends and a new is immediately initiated asychronously, mean while your client process the newly arrived data.

Silverlight gives you more options since is HTTP stack is purely asynchronous but you can get your hands on the stream to you as soon as data starts to arive by setting the `HttpWebRequest.AllowReadStreamBuffering` to `false`.  (Unlike XmlHttpRequest which always buffers).

Answer (score 1):

it's very easy to use the Comet ideas for notifications.  you don't even have to use a comet-specific framework.  simply do an ajax request with a callback on answer, wrap this on a loop and you have an event loop, just like a GUI app.  on the server side, don't bother answering the request until there's either an event, or a timeout (which is just a 'null' event).

Answer (score 0):

Flex and Flash have several AMF/XML remoting libraries available that support data pushing. I would certainly look into that.

http://raghuonflex.wordpress.com/2008/04/17/data-push-in-flex-with-backend/

These libraries use a [Comet -](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) like implementation to achieve this.